# Is the setting OFF/ON of the security flag different from enabling/disabling of fastboot?

Tags: security, fastboot, bootloader

I am following the book **XDA Developers Android Hackers Toolkit 2012**.
 In the beginning chapters , it says that :
The **second-stage bootloader** checks to see if the security flag is *on* **(S-ON)** or *off* **(S-OFF)** and depending on that , it checks for the signatures in kernel and OS that is to be loaded . The book says that if the security flag is **S-OFF** , then the bootloader no longer checks for signatures and also makes the entire system writable .
Now , coming to **fastboot** :
Fastboot is a protocol that allows low level commands to be sent to a device to do such things as write files to the OS . Most manufacturers , therefore , disable the fastboot protocol at the factory .

Can the security flag be **S-OFF** and fastboot be disabled ? Can anyone elaborate on the relation between the security flag and fastboot protocol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S-OFF is mainly found in HTC devices, and is a separate security mechanism whereas the `/system` directory cannot be mounted RW across boots.

It also restricts other features.

If S-OFF is enabled, fastboot can't be disabled, as fastboot would have to be enabled to turn S off. As such, fastboot would most likely be enabled, unless it was re-locked in some way (which would in turn lock S to ON).

Comment: Does a 'locked' bootloader refer to one with a disabled fastboot or one with S-ON ? Thanks

Comment: Locked bootloader = disabled fastboot.